# Play and Pause using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, swfobject

Hi am trying to Play and Pause SWF video using javascript. **When i provide local url path Play and pause works**

```
<p>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="219" HEIGHT="171" id="movie" ALIGN>
  <param NAME="movie" value="FOBfrictionlessPush.swf">
  <param NAME="quality" value="High">
  <param NAME="bgcolor" value="FFFFFF">
  <param name="_cx" value="5794">
  <param name="_cy" value="4524">
  <param name="FlashVars" value="-1">
  <param name="Src" value="FOBfrictionlessPush.swf">
  <param name="WMode" value="Window">
  <param name="Play" value="-1">
  <param name="Loop" value="0">
  <param name="SAlign" value>
  <param name="Menu" value="-1">
  <param name="Base" value>
  <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="Scale" value="ShowAll">
  <param name="DeviceFont" value="0">
  <param name="EmbedMovie" value="0">
  <param name="SWRemote" value>
  <EMBED src="FOBfrictionlessPush.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF  WIDTH="246" HEIGHT="187" NAME="movie" ALIGN=""  TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</object>
</p>
<p><a href="javascript:document.movie.Play()"><font face="Arial">&#9658;</font>play&nbsp; </a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <font face="Arial">
<a href="javascript:document.movie.StopPlay()">&#9553;pause</a></font></p>
```

But when i try to provide url from server it gives error on Play & pause.

```
<p>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="219" HEIGHT="171" id="movie" ALIGN>
  <param NAME="movie" value="<%=url%>">
  <param NAME="quality" value="High">
  <param NAME="bgcolor" value="FFFFFF">
  <param name="_cx" value="5794">
  <param name="_cy" value="4524">
  <param name="FlashVars" value="-1">
  <param name="Src" value="FOBfrictionlessPush.swf">
  <param name="WMode" value="Window">
  <param name="Play" value="-1">
  <param name="Loop" value="0">
  <param name="SAlign" value>
  <param name="Menu" value="-1">
  <param name="Base" value>
  <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="Scale" value="ShowAll">
  <param name="DeviceFont" value="0">
  <param name="EmbedMovie" value="0">
  <param name="SWRemote" value>
  <EMBED src="<%=url%>" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF  WIDTH="246" HEIGHT="187" NAME="movie" ALIGN=""  TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</object>
</p>
<p><a href="javascript:document.movie.Play()"><font face="Arial">&#9658;</font>play&nbsp; </a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <font face="Arial">
<a href="javascript:document.movie.StopPlay()">&#9553;pause</a></font></p>
```

Can someone guide please?

Comment: Can you provide an example with server URL as static value ?

Comment: try something like : `<param name="Src" value="http://www.yourserver.com/FOBfrictionlessPush.swf">`

Comment: Feels like an issue with rendering the url..
Can you just "puts" the url and and say its output..